# How to replace Text with Image on Google Slide using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

How do I get the same result using google Script, not with the Google Script API. I am trying to replace Text with Images on Google Slides using Google Script. Thank you in advance...

```
function insertImageCentered()
{
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  
  var requests = [{
    "replaceAllShapesWithImage": {
      "imageUrl": "https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vR5mi6ujksb_2WtTFmk39IPYBIBlJ6WkzM1nsys9cT4Wquik627DDIRXzoYTgHPKX3fcvJzG9inDmJt/pub?w=960&amp;h=720",
        "imageReplaceMethod": "CENTER_INSIDE",
        "pageObjectIds": [presentation.getSlides()[0].getObjectId()],
        "containsText": {
          "text": "{{CENTERED_SHAPE}}",
          "matchCase": false
        }
     }
   }];
  
   Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentation.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert your script using Google Slides API to the script using [Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides) without using Slides API.

  - From `How do I get the same result using google Script, not with the Google Script API.`, I understood that `Google Script API` you are thinking might be meaning Google Slides API. By this, I thought your goal like above.

In this case, I thought that the method of `replaceWithImage` can be used. When this method is used, the script becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Slides. And, please run the function of `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var searchText = "{{CENTERED_SHAPE}}";
  var imageUrl = "https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vR5mi6ujksb_2WtTFmk39IPYBIBlJ6WkzM1nsys9cT4Wquik627DDIRXzoYTgHPKX3fcvJzG9inDmJt/pub?w=960&amp;h=720";

  // 1. Retrieve 1st slide.
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];

  // 2. Replace the shape which has the text of "searchText" with the image of "imageUrl".
  slide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
    if (s.getText().asString().toLocaleUpperCase().includes(searchText.toLocaleUpperCase())) {
      s.replaceWithImage(imageUrl);
    }
  });
}
```

- In your script, `"matchCase": false` is used. At above script, I used `if (s.getText().asString().toLocaleUpperCase().includes(searchText.toLocaleUpperCase())) {` for this. When you want to use `"matchCase": true`, please modify it to `if (s.getText().asString().includes(searchText)) {`.
- And, if you want to replace the shape which has only the text of `{{CENTERED_SHAPE}}` with the image, please modify it to `if (s.getText().asString().trim() == searchText) {`.

#### Reference:

- [replaceWithImage(imageUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#replacewithimageimageurl)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Tanaike. What do you mean according to what I need. The code above works. But I found a new problem.
1. The slides I use are more than one
2. Image appears on the top left.

Is there a way to set the position of the Image?